# Conditional Import at build time in react js and react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, conditional-statements, next.js

I want to share my logic between react js and react native

here is my logic file. it is a HOC that wrap the design component.
I use `recompose` to create HOCs.

```
import {compose, withState} from 'recompose';
import FilterOptionsPostsPaginateRelay from './FilterOptionsPostsPaginateRelay';
import handlers from './handlers';
import {withRouter} from "next/router";

export default compose(
    withRouter
    FilterOptionsPostsPaginateRelay,
    withState('loading', 'setLoading', false),
    handlers,
)
```

All of the HOCs are sharable between the react js and react native but the `withRouter` that comes from next.js router

I want to conditional `import {withRouter} from "next/router";` or `import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';` in my logic file.

I know `recompose` has `branch` HOC that I can use but I want the condition checks at build time and prevent extra codes to my bundle and increase performance.

Comment: If you are using webpack to build, you can use `alias` to achieve this

Comment: I am using nextjs. can you tell me more about your solution?

Comment: can you share your project's `package.json`?

Comment: I added my package.json file

Comment: AFAIK you are using `webpack` in your project

Comment: I know that I am using webpack. can you share some code that I can understand what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can create `next.config.js` to custom webpack config to add alias for `router`.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
    // Perform customizations to webpack config
    // Important: return the modified config

    // Example using webpack option
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//));
    config.resolve.alias.router = process.env.IS_REACT_NATIVE ? 'react-navigation' : 'next/dist/client/router.js';
    return config
  },
};
```

then in your app, you need to use `require` to import `router`

```
const router = require('router');

const withRouter = router.withRouter || router.withNavigation;
```

Comment: thanks but I have a question. in react native side I dont use webpack. how react native side understand that `router` is alias for `react-navigation`

Comment: Can you share `package.json` of `react-native` project?

Comment: yes there are two projects. one for web and one for mobile. I added web project as dependency in mobile project and import from web logic HOCs in it.

Comment: I added package.json. `kweb` is my web dependency

Comment: Ok. Let me research it

Comment: I think the solution is to use `babel-plugin-module-resolver`

Comment: How do you import file from `reactjs` project in your `react-native` project?

Comment: I added web project as dependency to mobile project. see package.json. there is dependency for `"http://{git-token}@{git-host}/mohsen/kweb.git#feature"`. that is my web project

Comment: I mean how you import file from `reactjs` project in `react-native` project. Are you using something like this to import your file
`import lib from 'mohsen/kweb/lib';`

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution using `babel-plugin-module-resolver`

In web project I added following code to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "hybridRouter": "next/router"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

In mobile project I added following code to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "hybridRouter": "react-navigation"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And in my logic files I used this like

```
import HybridRouter from 'hybridRouter';
```

Now `HybridRouter` point to `next/router` in web project and `HybridRouter` points to `react-navigation` in mobile project

Answer (score 0):

You can have conditional imports using the `require` syntax. There is no need to mess with webpack, if you don't want to. Just do something like this in your case:

```
let withRouter;
try {
  //This is expected to fail if next/router is not available
  const router = require("next/router");
  withRouter = router.withRouter;
} catch(ex){
  const reactNav = require("react-navigation");
  withRouter = reactNav.withNavigation;
}

// Use withRouter like you would normally use withRouter from next/router or withNavigation from react-navigation
```

Comment: I think it will be caused to both `next/router` and `react-navigation` be bundled to project. Is this correct?

Comment: I believe this would only bundle both into the js bundle if both are available (in your dependencies). Not sure though..

Comment: This would still cause the final bundle to contain both require statements as the selection would have to be made at runtime.

Comment: @ThisCompSciGuy Only if they are both available